# Batch File malfunction

Tags: batch-file

This is a few lines from my batch file quiz that I made for friends. I have them answer the question "What topic would you like?" Earlier and they enter John or Computer. I want to be able to use that answer way later in the quiz, and I can't get it to go to a different option for the chosen topic.

So my question is, How can I get the REM to go to the correct topic?

```
:1
cls

REM Read settings from file
for /f %%S in (topic.ini) do set %%S

if %Mtopic%==John goto John
if %Mtopic%==john goto John
if %Mtopic%==Computer goto Com
if %Mtopic%==computer goto Com

:John
cls
echo.
echo================
echo Is john VERY strange? 
echo a.) Yeah.. STRANGE
echo b.) pfft strange? nah.
echo c.) I DONT CARE
echo.
echo================
set /p hi=

if %hi%==a goto crl
if not %hi%==a goto B

:crl 
echo Correct! 
echo. 
echo Continue? (y/n) 
set /p hi= 
if %ll% == y goto J2
if %ll% == Y goto J2
if %ll% == n goto John
if %ll% == N goto John
goto v2lvl2

:J2
cls
echo.
echo Not done.
echo.
pause
goto B

:Com
cls
echo.
echo >>>>>>>>>UPDATE LATER>>>>>>>>>>>
echo.
pause
goto B
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure about what you're asking for. Do you mean a piece of code that says something like, "What topic would you like?" and then, depending on what they answered, it would go to either John or Computer?

Then you would simply just use `set /p Mtopic=What topic would you like (john/computer)` or something to get input and after that you've already got everything done... right? But I feel like I don't really understand your question.